# Submit button not cooperating

Tags: html, css

I am sure this is a complete oversight on my part, but I have a button I would like to the immediate right of an input box, my html is:

```
    <input type="text" name="q" id="search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go!" />
```

and css is:

```
    #main input {
      margin: 30px auto auto 130px ;
      positiom: absolute;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 3px;
      padding: 6px;
      z-index: 3;  
      }
    #search {
      float: left;
      width: 550px;

    }
    #submit {
      width: 60px;  
   }
    #submit::-moz-focus-inner { 
       border: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }
```

The Go! button just sits directly below the left side of the submit box and any kind of margin tweaking is in vain bc it just stays there.  Also tried making the position absolute and  the button overlaps.

The Go! button will not position correctly - it is supposed to be to the right of my input box but it hangs below it instead.

How can I get it to position directly to the right my input box?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

```
html{
     background: url(images/bg5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
#main{ 
    width: 875px; 
    height: 350px; 
    background: url(images/form3.png) 0 0 no-repeat; 
    margin:250px auto; 
    z-index: 1; 
  }

#main form { 
    width: 850px; 
    height: 191px; 
    background: url(images/logo3.png) 0 0 no-repeat; 
    margin: -165px auto auto -90px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2; 
  }
#text {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: parisjetaime;
    margin: 189px auto auto 130px ;
    line-height: 30px;

}
#main input {
    margin: 30px auto auto 130px ;

    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 3px;
    padding: 6px;
    z-index: 3;  
}
#search {
    width: 550px;
}
#submit {
       width: 60px;
    float: right;    
}
#submit::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from your description what the actual problem is.

Comment: Sorry - the Go!  button will not position correctly - it is supposed to be to the right of my input box but it hangs below it instead.

Comment: Looks like you've got an answer, but also note that you misspelled "position" under #main input - that's probably not helping things much either ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is where your problem is, but it seems that by taking out `margin: 130px auto auto 200px ;` from `#submit` the Go! button is properly placed on the right of the search box.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ykRD/

**Edit**

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/H3gYM/1/

The `#main input` properties were overriding the #submit properties - in this case the margins are what made the Go! button be displaced. Placing [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) cancels the override and then tweaking the margins fixed the problem.

Comment: hmm, even taking out the margin still makes the button stay in the same spot =/

Comment: You should also remove the float:left from #search. This will help center the text bar a little better and I'm not sure that you really need it.

Comment: hmm, still hangs below the input bar - edited with the rest of my style.

Comment: @Sapp - can you set up a jsfiddle so we can see your issue in action?

Comment: Stupid me - I forgot to remove the margin on #main input, so now the Go! box is correctly to the right.  But is there a way to move both the input box and submit box down and to the right?  If I even give a margin to the #main input, they misaslign again.

Comment: @Sapp - have you tried removing the margin from form aswell? Also, just as a CSS tip, I would try to avoid using negative margins if you can, and I would also avoid using absolute positioning where possible.

Comment: Form needs a margin bc otherwise the logo is exactly in the middle of the form.

Comment: @Sapp - If you can set up a JSFiddle (it is worth registering for one -> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/user/signup/)) then it will be easier for us to help you debug as we will be seeing exactly what you see - images and everything.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H3gYM/1/
This should work. The 'main input' margins were overriding the margins you set for submit. If it's good I will update my answer and add explanations.

Comment: Is this accomplish able with class tags as well?  as in, if I had say a .error{   } tag, at the very end of my styles, would a !important allow me to tweak the margins?

Answer (score 0):

Why absolutely position your inputs? Here is a slightly trimmed down code which will put them next to each-other. The `float:left` was causing the height dis-joint because it causes the two elements to no longer be in the same 'line'

```
#main input {
   font-size: 18px;
   background: #fff;
   border: 3px;
   padding: 6px;
   z-index: 3;  
   }
#search {
   width: 550px;
}
#submit {
   width: 60px;
}
#submit::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: hmm, still hangs below the input bar - edited with the rest of my style.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to place the button just right to the text box, right? If so You need to float the input button and the textbox to left too;

```
#textbox {
 float: left;
}


#submit {
  width: 60px;  
  float: left;
```

}

This always work for me :) Let me know if it worked!